# How to enable cors in .Net Core for web api ajax call

Tags: ajax, .net-core

Am trying pull data from .net core web api using ajax call am getting the below error

**Failed to load http://localhost:8085/api/menu: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.**

**but am getting data sucessfully from postman.**

am trying below code for ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url: 'http:/localhost:8085/api/menu', 
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '{ }',
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log(data); 
    },
    failure: function (data) {  
        alert(data.responseText);  
    }, //End of AJAX failure function  
    error: function (data) {  
        alert(data.responseText);  
    } 
  });
});
```

I have added below tag in web.config file

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Please suggest your thoughts.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can define your policy in `Startup` file as a part of `ConfigureServices` method

for example:

```
{
  services.AddCors(c => {
      c.AddPolicy("policyName", p => {
          p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod();
      });
  });
}
```

and then in `Configure` method

`app.UseCors("policyName");`

Comment: Thanx for your reply i have tried above but still am getting different  issue jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:5000/localhost:8085/api/menu?{%20} 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you address includes localhost twice - I'm 99% sure there is a bug somewhere and it should probably be either localhost:5000 or localhost:8085

Comment: There is a bug i fixed and now working fine thank you again.

Comment: perfect, please mark this solution as an valid answer so it's visible for others who have the same problem that it works.

Comment: Is this to be configured in the caller webapp or the calee web api?

Comment: in calle web api startup file